# Join table and take name into model MVC , LINQ, C#, Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, select

Here is my Office model

```
public class Office 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my Worker model

```
public class Worker 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int OfficeID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string OfficeColor { get; set; }
    }
```

what I want is to get all workers with LINQ with OfficeColor the Color of the specified OfficeID color

Comment: Is `OfficeID` a navigation property to `Office` (and if so does the `Worker ` model also include `public virtual Office Office { get; set; }`

Comment: `asp.net-mvc` tag is irrelevant. `linq` tag is too broad. Linq to what? Objects? SQL? EF? If EF, which version (EF 6, EF Core)?

Comment: If OfficeColor is not mapped then there is no data on this property from database. What are you trying to achieve? can you write example?

Comment: Please show you own first efforts because they probably clarify what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to make a relation between two EF models (code first approach):

```
public class Worker 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    // [NotMapped]
    // public string OfficeColor { get; set; }
}

public class Office 
{
    private ICollection<Worker> workers;

    public Office 
    {
       this.workers = new HashSet<Worker>();
    } 

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Workers
    {
        get { return this.workers; }
        set { this.workers = value; }
    }
}

// and get all workers from Db
public class Program
{
     public static void Main()
     {
       IEnumerable<WorkerViewModel> workers = DbContext.Workers.All().Select(w => 
          new WorkerViewModel()
          {
               Id = w.Id,
               OfficeId = w.Office.Id,
               FullName = w.FullName,
               OfficeColor = w.Office.Color
          })
          .ToList();
     }
}
```

Comment: sry man but your code gives a loot of errors

Comment: I write it here without intellisence. Just as an abstraction. You should fit the code to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myColor = "Red";
            var results = (from office in Office.offices
                           join worker in Worker.workers on office.ID equals worker.ID
                           select new { office = office, worker = worker })
                            .Where(x => x.office.Color == myColor)
                            .Select(x => new {
                                ID = x.worker.ID,
                                OfficeID = x.worker.OfficeID, 
                                FullName = x.worker.FullName, 
                                OfficeColor = x.office.Color  
                            }).ToList();

        }
    }
    public class Office
    {
        public static List<Office> offices { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public Office()
        {
            office = new Office();
        }
    }
    public class Worker
    {
        public static List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int OfficeID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        //[NotMapped]
        public string OfficeColor { get; set; }
        public Worker()
        {
            workers = new List<Worker>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry , I have may not explain it correctly. What I want to get is a list of all of my Workers and every worker should be like. [[ID :1 , OfficeID: 2, FullName: "John", OfficeColor : "Red" ]], [[ID :2 , OfficeID: 3, FullName: "Peter", OfficeColor : "Brown"]] [[[ID :3 , OfficeID: 2, FullName: "Helen", OfficeColor : "Red"]]

Comment: I updated code.  The Select needed to be modified.